# Is it possible to --disable-web-security on Travis Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, github, travis-ci, chromium

I am developing a project which requires `--disable-web-security` for testing. I use Karma with the following settings:

```
    browsers: [
        "ch"
    ],
    customLaunchers: {
        "ch": {
            "base": "Chrome",
            "flags": ["--disable-web-security"]
        }
    },
```

and

```
if (process.env.TRAVIS)
    options.customLaunchers.ch.flags.push("--no-sandbox");
```

This works properly on localhost with Chrome v69.0.3497.100 win7 x64.

I am trying to run the same code on Travis (by pushing the changes to GitHub) with the following yml:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "9"
before_install:
  - export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
  - sleep 5
```

I guess we are talking about 2 different browsers with the same engine here, since `Chromium != Chrome`, but I am not sure. Anyways, I got an error message by trying to build on Travis:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:9876" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

That clearly indicates that web security is enabled. Is there any way to disable web security on Travis?

## Solution:

Using Trusty with real Chrome solved it:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "9"
dist: trusty
addons:
  chrome: stable
before_install:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
  - sleep 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#using-the-chrome-addon-in-the-headless-mode) you can run Chrome headless by writing the following in your `.travis.yml` config file

```
dist: trusty
addons:
  chrome: stable
before_install:
  - # start your web application and listen on `localhost`
  - google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 http://localhost &
```

As for your Karma configuration file, check [this page](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/chrome#karma-chrome-launcher). It indicates that you have to add one more flag.

> For security reasons, Google Chrome is unable to provide sandboxing when it is running in the container-based environment.
>
> To use Chrome in the container-based environment, pass the --no-sandbox flag to the chrome executable.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless', 'ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],

    // you can define custom flags
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Be aware that I have ***Never*** done this before. I am just pointing you to the correct documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but I am already running Chrome in a container environment. The problem that the `--disable-web-security` flag does not disable the web security in this environment, while it disables it in the developer environment...

Comment: maybe because you try to use chromium `export CHROME_BIN=chromium-browser` and you are setting chrome `"base": "Chrome"`..

Comment: As far as I understand your code the `before_install` part is totally unnecessary, because the karma Chrome launcher will start the browser and NPM will start the Karma server and there is no other server side app in this project. The current code uses x11, but I can replace it with headless Chrome. This is a very old code, Chrome and headless Chrome wasn't available when I first used it and since then I copy-paste it to my client side projects. I'll read your linked articles and give it a try after that.

Comment: @inf3rno the before_install part is copy/pasted from the first link in my answer and as I told you, I have never done this so I am not sure this really helps